# Template argument deduction fails on C++14

Tags: c++, templates

I was trying to compile this code but it fails on `C++14` while it works on `C++17`

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template <typename F>
struct S {
    explicit S(F&& fn): fn(std::move(fn)) {}
    F fn;
    ~S() { fn(); }
};


int main(){
    S obj([]() noexcept {
        std::printf("Foo\n");
    });                                                                                                 
}
```

I [see that](https://godbolt.org/z/K9T61PG4P) in `C++17` the constructor of `S` has been invoked as

```
   call    S<main::{lambda()#1}>::S(main::{lambda()#1}&&)
```

which indicates that the compiler deduced the template argument. Is there a way to get this code compiling in `C++14` other than doing something as follows?

```
auto fn = []() noexcept {
    std::printf("Foo\n");
};
S<decltype(fn)> obj(std::move(fn));
```

Comment: The code relies on a C++17 feature. There is no way to build it as C++14 unaltered.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I see. Could you please point me to the specific feature that you're referring to?

Comment: [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). Literally the thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class template argument deduction ([CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)) was only introduced in C++17 . You can deduce the argument with a function:

```
template <typename F>
S<F> make_S(F&& fn) { return S<F>{std::forward<F>(fn)}; }

int main(){
    auto obj = make_S([]() noexcept {
        std::printf("Foo\n");
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that this is slightly different to the c++17 semantics. The class would not accept lvalues implicitly, whereas this will.

Comment: Also, there's a requirement of `S` to allow copies/moves.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with a fixed function signature then this works in C++14 too.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct S 
{
    template <typename F>
    explicit S(F&& fn) : 
        m_fn(fn)
    {
    }

    ~S() 
    { 
        m_fn(); 
    }

private:
    std::function<void ()> m_fn;
};


int main() {
    S obj([]() noexcept 
    {
            std::cout << "Foo\n";
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can even abstract away the return value of the function by assigning `[fn] () { fn(); }` to `m_fn` instead of `fn` directly.

Comment: You no longer need template constructor then, `explicit S(std::function<void()> fn)` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Jarod42 Point well made